# How to get the number of active visitors in a node.js (express) website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building a website using node.js and express.js. I want to build a new functionality for me - the developer/administrator, where, at any moment, to somehow to get the number of active visitors on my website, so I can know to schedule a downtime (for every new upadate/deployment) when the traffic is low.

What I mean by "active visitors" is that they are working on the front-end, i.e. the have an open browser window. Maybe, they have just performed a request? See? I do not know where to start...

I do not want to use Google Analytics just for this simple case.

I have not tried anything, because I do now know where to start.

Comment: If your server is stateless, as most of the express servers are, you've no way to see how many active users you have on your website. You can count the number of requests in the last 20 minutes and get an estimation for it

Comment: Yes, I thought of that. But, it is very differrent for me if one user made a lot of requests or a lot of users made a single request. So, can i count the "unique" sessions of requests? Maybe, count the different IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

#### The first solution (accurate).

By using `socket.io`. so you need to create a `socket.io` server. and connect to it from the front end.
now you can get how many users open your website at any time.

#### The second solution.

1. Your front end generates a unique id for every browser session.
2. Your front end sends this id with any request to the back-end.
3. In the back-end, you will create middleware to get this id and insert it or update `lastActive` date

   1. If exists. update `lastActive` date
   2. if not exist. insert it with the current date
4. If you need to get the currently active users count you can select the count of records at the last 1 minute using `lastActive`.

NOTE: In the second solution, you can optimize it by using Redis.

#### Second solution example

[image]

Comment: I think redis is the best solution. Both socket.io and SQL sound like a overkill

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina Yes, totally agree with you. In the first solution, you didn't need to use Redis or SQL DB. But if you don't want to use socket.io you will need to go with the second solution. so need to use Redis or SQL DB.